# Optimization problem for routes

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coding-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

Let a group of farms each have a $p$-letter name. No two farms have the same name, however, and they all only consist of x's and z's. For example, if $p=2$, then xx, zz, xz, zx are the farms in the state. Bus rides take farmers from farm to farm but they only have routes from and to farms that differ in name by exactly one letter. For example, there is a bus ride connecting xx and xz. The state has stores on different farms.

(a) If the state government only places stores on farms in a way as to allow farms access to one store via a single bus ride, what, in terms of $p$, can the max number of stores that the state has in total be?

(b) If the government instead wants every farm to have access via a single bus ride or less to a store, what is the minimum number of stores, in terms of $p$, that the state can have in total?

Comment: Are there always $2^p$ farms?  Then you have a $p-$ dimensional hypercube.  I don't understand the first set of conditions.  What does it mean to prevent any farm from being more than one bus ride away from multiple stores?  Especially in light of the statement:  it is ok if some farms do not have a single bus ride that connects them to stores.  Please give examples to elucidate this.

Also, what is your question?  What have you done on this?

Comment: So if $p=3$ we could place $4$ stores at $000, 101, 011,110$ is that right?  Each farm either has a store on it, or is at distance $1$ from exactly one store.  I would think induction on $p$ is the way to go.  Here I'm addressing the first set of conditions.   Also, I don't think any of your tags are appropriate.  It seems to me that the right tag is or combinatorics, and perhaps graph theory.

Comment: Which farm is it in the example I gave?

Comment: @saulspatz In your example, the farm at $111$ can access three stores, at $110,101$ and $011$.

Comment: Please don't self-delete your question after receiving an answer.  This is considered rude to the answerer on this site.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. In addition to the problem statement, we look for context with each post. What is the source of the problem? Why is it of interest? What attempts have you made? Posts that are only a problem statement are often put on hold, and may be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is in general an open problem. Each store is either on or adjacent to a total of $p+1$ farms, so if no farm can access a multiple stores, then there will be at most
$$
\frac{2^p}{p+1}
$$
stores. Similarly, if every farm can access at least one store, there will be at least that many stores.

If $p+1$ is a power of two, then that number is an integer, and it can be attained for both problems.

> Assume $p+1=2^n$. Consider a particular farm. Let $b_i$ be a sequence of $p$ numbers, each $0$ or $1$ according to whether the $i^{th}$ letter of that farm's name is $z$ or $x$. Furthermore, let $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_p$ be a list without repeats of the nonzero vectors in $\mathbb F_2^n$ (vectors of length $n$ with entries in $\{0,1\}$, with addition and scaling coordinate-wise $\pmod 2$). Note there are $2^n-1=p$ such vectors. Then that farm will be labeled with the vector
>   $$
> \sum_{i=1}^p b_iv_i\in \mathbb F_2^n
> $$
>   Perform this labeling for every farm. The farms labeled with the zero vector will be the ones who are given a store. You can show that exactly $2^{p-n}$ vectors are given a store, and every farm will either have a store or be adjacent to exactly one store.

When $p+1$ is not a power of two, I believe it is as of yet an open problem to determine the optimal packing and covering numbers. An upper (lower) bound is given by rounding $2^p/(p+1)$ down (up) to the nearest integer. For the best known packing numbers for various values of $p$, see the first column of the table in https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/codes/binary-1.html. The number in the row labeled $q$ gives the largest number of non-overlapping stores you can have when $p=q-1$. For example, for farms with names of length $p=18$, you can have at least $10496$ but certainly no more than $13104$ stores.

Comment: This method is known more generally as a one error correcting hamming code.